# ASP.Net Library name conflict between Ektron app_code and library

Tags: webforms, quartz.net, ektron

I've got an Ektron 8.2 site, and I was trying to integrate Quartz.NET into it, in order to run some scheduling. Quartz.NET requires a library Common.Logging. This library introduces a conflict and breaks the Ektron code in App_Code/VBCode.

E.g. the following code from Utilities.vb

```
Case Is = Common.EkEnumeration.FolderType.Community
      imageURL &= "images/ui/icons/folderCommunity.png"
Case Common.EkEnumeration.FolderType.Catalog
      imageURL &= "images/ui/icons/folderGreen.png"
```

now gives a compile time error-

```
App_Code\VBCode\Utilities.vb(703,0): error BC30456: 'EkEnumeration' is not a member of 'Common'.
```

It appears that Common.Logging is conflicting with Ektron.Cms.Common (the Ektron files have a `Imports Ektron.Cms` statement). Is it possible to specify the priority on libraries? Or namespace an imported library?

**Update**
The Utilities.vb code is written by Ektron. I'd like to either make no changes to this code, or minimal changes, as any changes would need to be re-done upon Ektron upgrades. This is really a clash between 2 libraries - Ektron and Quartz.Net. Can I resolve this clash without changing the code of either library? Is there a configuration setting for aliasing libraries?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the full namespace, Ektron.Cms.Common.EkEnumeration, rather than relying on the include to sort things out automatically.

I.e.

```
Case Is = Ektron.Cms.Common.EkEnumeration...
```

Not elegant, but should get you working again.

Comment: Thanks, but as update to question explains, I prefer to either not change the Ektron code, or at least minimise the changes. Using the full namespace requires a lot of changes to the Ektron code.

Comment: Got it. Hadn't realized it was Ektron's code throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using EkCommon = Ektron.Cms.Common;
```

So your code would instead look like:

```
EkCommon.EkEnumeration.FolderType.Community
```

Comment: Thanks, but as update to question explains, I prefer to either not change the Ektron code, or at least minimise the changes. Using a namespace alias would require a lot of changes to the Ektron code.